# tk.messagebox.showerror() appears in wrong condition

Tags: string, csv, tkinter, openfiledialog

I got this code below and wherever I select a csv file the messagebox.showerror function activates while it should not. Any ideas? It works perfectly when I upload a xlsx or xls file.

I want to ensure that a user only uploads a .csv or a .xls or a .xlsx file and for this I try some error handling with ifs. Could it be a wrong if logic? could it be a string issue? I checked type and printed the filetype variable and it was giving csv.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog



#######################################################################################################
##### FUNCTIONS
#######################################################################################################
df_root= False
df= False
Error = None

def openfile():
    global df_root
    df_root = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:",
                           filetypes =(("All Files","*.*"),[("Excel Files",".xlsx .xls"),("CSV Files",".csv")]),
                           title = "Choose a file.")
    filetype= df_root.split(".")[1]
    print(filetype)

    global df

    if filetype == "csv":   
        df=pd.read_csv(df_root)
    if filetype =="xlsx" or filetype=="xls":
        df=pd.read_excel(df_root)
    else:
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Filetype Error","The selected file must be: .csv .xls or .xlsx")
        df= False
# Create the Root tkinter object
root = tk.Tk()


##### - Screen Size Options

# Get Screen width and Height
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
screen_ratio = round(screen_width/screen_height,1)
# Set root to zoomed state
root.state("zoomed")

# Set the root mainloop to keep the program open
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you have `("All Files", "*.*")` there?
Also you never actually call `openfile` in your example.

Comment: @TheLizzard: `("All Files", "*.*")` is a very common idiom for file dialogs. It gives the user the chance to open any file, not just one with a predefined suffix.

Comment: Super thanks so in order to avoid all this error handling I simply don't allow the user to load anything else.

Comment: @BryanOakley From OP's question: *"I want to ensure that a user only uploads a .csv or a .xls or a .xlsx file"*. That is why I assumed that OP didn't really need the `"*.*"`

Comment: @TheLizzard: "a csv file" is a bit ambiguous. You can have a file named "my_data.txt" which is a csv file. The fact that a file is a csv file isn't tied to the filename, just as it's possible to have a file named "my_data.csv" which _isn't_ in a csv format. Software exists to serve the user, and limiting their choices isn't always the most user-friendly thing to do.

Comment: @BryanOakley Correct, my bad. I assumed that file extensions must match the file type :D. Although OP's program handles the files based on the file extension.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a `.csv` file to test your code and you're getting this bug, I believe your error is in:

```py
if filetype =="xlsx" or filetype=="xls":
```

should be:

```py
elif filetype =="xlsx" or filetype=="xls":
```

Because if it's a `.csv`, the `if filetype =="xlsx" or filetype=="xls":` will not pass and therefore will raise your error.